# how to change the color of loader sematic ui animation?

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react, semantic-ui-css

how to change the color of loader sematic ui animation?
I tried to prescribe different parameters in style, but I found how to change the animation itself. Nothing works and I didn't find any information in the library api.I have highlighted with blue dots the elements whose colors I want to change
[image]
import React from "react";
import { Dimmer, Loader } from "semantic-ui-react";

```
const TestLoader = () => (
  <Dimmer active>
    <Loader
      size="massive"
      style={{
        backgroundColor: "green",
        borderRadius: "50%",
      }}
    />
  </Dimmer>
);

const CheckboxExample = () => {
  const loader = true;

  if (loader) {
    return <TestLoader />;
  }
};

export default CheckboxExample;
```